# My android app starts service before display the layout

Tags: android, layout, service

I'm writing android app, here is the code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), ttt.class));
}
```

ttt is class extends Service that keeps displaying a Dialog every 15 mins 
when it starts, it first wait 15 mins and show the dialog, then it will display the layout.

the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` is before `startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), ttt.class));`
why it don't display the layout first, but start the service first?

How can I display the layout first, then after 15 mins and display the dialog?

Comment: You should not use Service to deal with UI elements (a Dialog).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly please rename your service ttt to some proper name. You can start a AlarmManager inside your onCreate.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ttt.class);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(getBaseContext(), 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 15*60*1000, pintent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a handler for this.
try something like :

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {

                      Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ttt.class);
                      startActivity(i);
                  }
              }, 900000);
```

Hope it helps